# How do I know a non-blocking SocketChannel is connected?

Tags: java, nio

From the javadoc of finishConnect:

> If this channel is in non-blocking mode then this method will return
>   false if the connection process is not yet complete

Does that mean I have to do periodical pulling on isConnected() to know that the channel is connected? (the pulling behavior is sort of "blocking")

It seems there's no callback on "connected" state.

Any suggestions or any alternatives?

Thanks

Leon

Comment: What do you want to do when the `SocketChannel` is connected? I.e. why do you think you need to keep polling `isConnected()`?

Comment: Can I write bytebuffer to SocketChannel even if it's not connected? I didn't try it but my first guess is only when it's connected I should start writing data.